# Inserting Data into a table

Tags: mysql

Hi all i have a pretty basic question but i cant pickup where im wrong in my Syntax. Im supposed to create a concat message that shows what items are discounted against a certain constraint. The first step is adding data that meets the requirement. In this case it is an ORDER that is created after the 30th of April 2019, as shown below

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS
   (ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_CODE, EMPLOYEE_ID, ORDER_DATE, REQUIRED_DATE, SHIPPED_DATE, SHIP_VIA, FREIGHT, SHIP_NAME, SHIP_ADDRESS, SHIP_CITY, SHIP_REGION, SHIP_POSTAL_CODE, SHIP_COUNTRY)
  VALUES
   (4000,'SAVEA', 4, STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2019', '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2019', '%m/%d/%Y'),
    STR_TO_DATE('02/28/2019', '%m/%d/%Y'), 'Ausralia Post', 15.63, 'Titanic', '185 League Street.',
    'Sydney', 'AB', '56728', 'Australia');

    INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL
    ( ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME ,UNIT_PRICE, QUANTITY, DISCOUNT )
    VALUES
    (4000, 'Konbu',6,10,0);

    INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL
    ( ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME ,UNIT_PRICE, QUANTITY, DISCOUNT )
    VALUES
    (4000, 'Alice Mutton',39,10,0);
```

The next step is too create a table to store the message

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGES (

SIZE VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL


);
```

the next step, which is where i believe my syntax error lies, is to create the concat message itself

```
  INSERT INTO MESSAGE  
  SELECT CONCAT('Order', ORDERS.ORDER_ID, 'submitted on',ORDERS.ORDER_DATE,'includes  a discontinued product', ORDER_DETAIL.PRODUCT_NAME)
  FROM PRODUCT
  JOIN ORDER_DETAIL ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME = ORDER_DETAIL.PRODUCT_NAME JOIN ORDERS ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_ID
  WHERE PRODUCT.DISCONTINUED = 'N' AND ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > STR_TO_DATE('04/30/2019','%m/%d/%Y');
```

im following a passed assingment example to the Tee and i dont understand why it brings No results. Below ill post the tables used

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
    PRODUCT_NAME    VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    SUPPLIER_NAME   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY_NAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY_PER_UNIT   VARCHAR(20),
    UNIT_PRICE      DECIMAL(10,2)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    UNITS_IN_STOCK  DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    UNITS_ON_ORDER  DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0, 
    REORDER_LEVEL   DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    DISCONTINUED    CHAR(1)     NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'N',
    CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCT PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORY_NAME FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_NAME) REFERENCES CATEGORY(CATEGORY_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_NAME FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_NAME) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE CHECK (UNIT_PRICE >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNITS_IN_STOCK CHECK (UNITS_IN_STOCK >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNITS_ON_ORDER CHECK (UNITS_ON_ORDER >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_REORDER_LEVEL CHECK (REORDER_LEVEL >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_DISCONTINUED CHECK (DISCONTINUED in ('Y','N'))
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE      DATE        NOT NULL,
    REQUIRED_DATE   DATE,
    SHIPPED_DATE    DATE,
    SHIP_VIA        VARCHAR(40),
    FREIGHT         DECIMAL(10,2)           DEFAULT 0,
    SHIP_NAME       VARCHAR(40),
    SHIP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(60),
    SHIP_CITY       VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_REGION     VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_POSTAL_CODE    VARCHAR(10),
    SHIP_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_CODE FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_SHIP_VIA FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_VIA) REFERENCES SHIPPER(COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL
(
    ORDER_ID         DECIMAL(9) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_NAME     VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
    UNIT_PRICE       DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    QUANTITY         DECIMAL(9) NOT NULL    DEFAULT 1 ,
    DISCOUNT         DECIMAL(4,2)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_DETAIL PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_ID FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT_NAME FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_NAME) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_UNIT_PRICE CHECK (UNIT_PRICE >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_QUANTITY CHECK (QUANTITY > 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_DISCOUNT CHECK (DISCOUNT between 0 and 1)
);
```

Comment: What is the exact error message, or what is the problem?  Note that the message you are trying to insert appears to be derived data, and as such, you might just want to create a view instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i dont get error its just that theres no result. When i go to select all from message theres nothing in the table.

Comment: Then check your data, as the query itself is likely just returning no records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my concat statement results in an empty set

Comment: @AndrewVan We don't have your data, so how did you expect us to figure out which condition in your `SELECT` sub-query is causing nothing to be found? **Debug** your SQL, e.g. by building it one step at a time, executing it each step, until you add something that causes empty result. You then know which condition causes the issue. Just run the `SELECT` without the `INSERT` until you get it working.

Comment: @Andreas if you want all the insert statements ill have to post it seperatly as its over 3000 lines

Comment: @AndrewVan No, I want *you* to **debug** your own `SELECT` statement. I see no attempt at doing your own research for this problem. I even explained one way of doing that: *Build it one step at a time*. E.g. start with `SELECT * FROM ORDERS`. Do you get data? Add `WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > STR_TO_DATE('04/30/2019','%m/%d/%Y')`. Do you still get data? Add `JOIN` to `ORDER_DETAIL`. Do you still get data? Add `JOIN` to `PRODUCT`. Do you still get data? Add `PRODUCT.DISCONTINUED = 'N'` check.  Do you still get data?

Answer (score 2):

To debug this, first do just the select part, don’t do the insert part.

I bet the problem is around how you specify the date. Try dropping that out of the query and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was putting the date in wrong, i was doing day month then year not month day and year